# Glympse API event handling

Tags: glympse

I am trying to launch glympse app by using an intent and receiving the information through broadcast. Is there any way that I will be notified about the events occurring like ticket removed, expired, updated etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is.

We created a library project to make this easier for you. It can be found here: https://github.com/Glympse/glympse-app-sdk/tree/master/Android/GlympseIntentsLib

A sign-in is required to view these documents that might be helpful.

Tutorial: https://developer.glympse.com/Content/client/app/guides/Glympse_Intents_Tutorial.html
Reference Docs: https://developer.glympse.com/Content/client/app/guides/Glympse_Intents_Reference.html

Specifically, check out the method CreateGlympseParams.setCallbackAction(String). This will allow you to set an action which will be used to broadcast a message back to your app.

Another option is to use CreateGlympseParams.setEventsListener(EventsListener). With this method, you can supply an object that implements GlympseApp.EventsListener. Using this method, our library handles the broadcast under the covers and your object's methods will be invoked as the event occur.

Comment: I was not able to find any callback params which can handle when the user cancels the glympse.How to handle the case if the user cancels the operation before done_sending event has occurred?? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I'm having the original author of the lib take a look today, but my guess is that if you call the intent using startActivityForResult() it will return with resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED in that case.

Comment: yeah...but this doesnt work when i set a callbackAction. What do i do in that case?